# HTML form with underlining for handwritten information

Tags: html, webforms, presentation, underline

I need to make some forms in HTML that a customer will need to print and write some entries by hand then scan or fax.

So I want there to be an area for signing like "Sign ____________"

Underscores are all good if the underline is a limited length, but what if I have a number of lines that need to go all the way across the page (or in some cases table cell) with some text in front of each??

So:

```
Item 1: ____________
An Item 2: _________
This is item 3: ____
1 more item: _______
```

The trouble is if I use underscores, the underscores don't finish at the same places and it looks wrong or it warps the size of the cell. The best thing would be to underline white space but that's just not possible.

Comment: And for heaven's sake, put some vertical space between those user-fillable blanks! I get *really* ticked off at people who provide forms where all the blanks are just 1/8 inch high. Have these dolts ever tried to hand-fill out their own forms??

Comment: good question, none of the answers below work well with IE though...

Answer (score 6):

So build some block elements with a `border-bottom`. Those will look like underlines and you can play with colors, thicknesses and whatnot.

**A pragmatic solution:** I would make each line a 2-column table, give the left column (with the text) a width of `0%` (which will expand to the minimum needed) and the right column (empty with underline) a width of `100%` (which will take up the remaining space); and I'd put an empty block with a bottom border into that right table cell.

This design of mine violates some ideals held by many other Web designers. I'm not saying this is a fantastic or very standards-compliant design, I only claim it's simple and it works.

Comment: If tables can be useful in a situation like this, then they can't all be evil, right?

Comment: I keep getting into fights with CSS purists about this. I try to stay out of the argument, I just trot out my approach and let the question askers decide which they prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in `<pre> tags </pre>`.

It will use a monospaced font so your underscore 'lines' will end at the same position.
You may have noticed this also happens in your question above ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CSS rule like

```
text-decoration: underline;
```

or

```
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
```

Comment: You wanna take the `l` out of "decoration" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tried to find the solution myself, a while ago. So, the key is:

> The best thing would be to underline white space but that's just not possible.

It actually *is* possibe, just `<u>&nbsp;</u>` or `<u>&emsp;</u>`.

Here's an example of a form, where fields are placed inline to each other:

```html
    <div>
      <nobr>
      First name:
      <u> &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp;</u>
      </nobr>
      <nobr>
      Last name:
      <u> &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp;</u>
      </nobr>
      <nobr>
      Contact phone:
      <u> &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp;</u>
      </nobr>
    </div>
```

And here's an example of form, where fields are organized on top of each other, and ___ part goes right, is limited by right bondary of div, and doesn't wrap unnecessarily:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <style>
    myLn {
     display: block;
     width: 30%;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    
    
    <myLn>
    Name:
    <u> &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp;</u>
    </myLn>
    
    <myLn>
    Address:
    <u> &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp;</u>
    </myLn>
    
    <myLn>
    More info:
    <u> &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp;</u>
    </myLn>
    
    <myLn>
    <u> &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp;</u>
    </myLn>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Hope it helps.